# reset timer after closing the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple countdown that runs when I open a modal, it works when I open it once. My problem is when I close and open it again, the counter shows different counters at the same time. I tried to put `timer(0)` but didn't work, I use also `off()` but the counter doesn't work anymore.

Hope you help me thanks.

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
   $('.modal').show();
  timer(60);
});
$('.close').click(function(){
   $('.modal').hide();
});

function timer(seconds){
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    seconds--;
      $('.note span').text(seconds);
        if (seconds == 0) {
        // Display a login box
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
   }, 1000);
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="note"><span>60</span></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear the interval when the modal is closed, as well as resetting the `seconds` text to `60`. Have an `interval` variable within scope of both the `timer` and the `.close` handler, and call `clearInterval` on close:

```js
let interval;
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
  $('.modal').show();
  timer(60);
});
$('.close').click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $('.note span').text('60');
  $('.modal').hide();
});

function timer(seconds) {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    seconds--;
    $('.note span').text(seconds);
    if (seconds == 0) {
      // Display a login box
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="note"><span>60</span></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the help sir, Ill accept the answer after 10 mins sir.